Unable to deploy Azure Resource Group from Devops using ARM template and Powershell
I am trying to deploy azure resources [Resource Group] from Devops using ARM Template and Powershell. Below is the setup

Created a service principal with secret.
Assign Contributor role in subscription level for the service principal.
Create a service connection in Devops with that service principal.
Assign the service connection in Yaml pipeline for subscription.
YAML code
Powershell scripts to deploy the Resource group with ARM template.
Powershell scripts
But no success. Azure context is set properly.

Error
error

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment command needs the resource Group pre-existing. You can manually create the resource Group and re-run your pipeline or add the creating resource group command in your powershell script.

To create a resource group why do I need to create the same resource group manually? New-AzResourceGroupDeployment is the command to create a resource group with ARM template.

To create the resource group only, you should use "New-AzResourceGroup" command, the New-AzResourceGroupDeployment is used to add a deployment to the pre-existing resource group, i added the details below. thanks

The New-AzResourceGroupDeployment is used to add a deployment to the pre-existing resource group, if the resource group doesn't exist, it will report the error in your screenshot.
To create a resource group, you can simply use New-AzResourceGroup which doesn't require ARM template. Then you can start to deploy on this resource group.
The ARM template on my side is used to deploy storage account on the resource group, fixed the pipeline and powershell as below for example:
stages:
  - stage: Partner
    displayName: Dev
    jobs:
      - deployment: Dev_deployment
        displayName: Dev deployment
        pool:
          vmImage: Windows-latest
        environment: Dev
        strategy:
         runOnce:
           deploy:
             steps:
               - checkout: self
               - task: AzurePowerShell@5
                 displayName: Lab Dev Deployment
                 inputs:
                   azureSubscription: 'ARMConn4'
                   ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
                   Inline: |
                     Set-Location $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
                     ./deployment/master.ps1 -environment "dev" -rgconfig @{"dev"=@{"rgname"="rg_DevOpsCICDNew"}}    # rgconfig is required as hashtable type in your powershell
                   azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

The powershell：
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $environment,
        #[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][hashtable] $commonconfig,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][hashtable] $rgconfig
    )
    
    $ARMTemplateFilePath = Resolve-Path -Path .\ARMtemplate\resourcegroup\resourcegroup.json
    $ARMTemplateParamFilePath = Resolve-Path -Path .\ARMtemplate\resourcegroup\parameters.json

    Write-Host $ARMTemplateFilePath
    Write-Host $ARMTemplateParamFilePath
    Write-Host $rgconfig[$environment].rgname

    # $Deployment = @{
    #     ResourceGroupName = $rgconfig[$environment].rgname
    #     TemplateFile = $ARMTemplateFilePath
    #     TemplateParameterFile = $ARMTemplateParamFilePath
    # }
    New-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgconfig[$environment].rgname -Location "East US"
    sleep 60   # add delay after resource group creation

    #New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @Deployment
    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $rgconfig[$environment].rgname -TemplateFile $ARMTemplateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $ARMTemplateParamFilePath

    Write-Host "Deployment is complted for ResourceGroup :" $rgconfig[$environment].rgname


The pipeline succeeds, and resource group created, deployment(storageaccount) completed on the resource group.


